# Apple watch SE battery sharp decline. What can I do to hold over temporarily?

Tags: battery, apple-watch

I have an apple watch SE that I've owned for three and a half years. I've started to notice that the battery is starting to run down a lot faster. I looked in settings and as it stands the battery only has 76% of its original capacity. It's given me the "Service Recommended" notice. I'm currently looking into my options at the moment, but I need something to hold over for now. I've missed several texts as my phone is currently mailed in for service and now my watch is declining. I don't want to take the 5-9 days on the mail in for the watch while my phone is still being fixed. All I need to know is what can I do to keep battery consumption to a minimum for a bit.

Comment: If there is an Apple Store near you (or other Apple-approved shop), I find that they are quicker to turn things around than mailing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Low Power Mode in watchOS 9 and later reduces the amount of power that your Apple Watch uses so that you can save battery life."

https://support.apple.com/en-us/108320

Comment: I only have up to 8.6. It's a secondhand watch.

Comment: Then go through the settings and turn off everything you can do without. That's all you can do.